# Initial startup and advanced concepts

Tags: php

I am in the process of creating my first website which I hope will have a small to medium following. I have the basic tools to get it going, but with each step further into the project I'm confronted with the feeling that the site will be inadequate, especially when I look into concepts that I know very little about such as Memcache, datamappers, frameworks and MVC.

Now my question is, what would you, the pros, recommend I do. Should I just hack at it so I can launch it asap and then gradually update the code or should I study and implement these techniques and features before launch?

If I could except comments as answers I would.

Comment: Just start coding, don't expect miracles. Your first website, when you look at it after couple years, will look like crap when it comes to good practices. But during the process try to learn these concepts (frameworks, MVC, ORM, caching etc.) and understand why you need them. You will probably need to rewrite your whole site anyway, if you are just beginning.

Comment: @Tadeck:  I agree with everything but the word *probably* in your last sentence.  Grasshopper *will* need to rewrite it.  That's just the way it goes.

Comment: Nice comment @Tadeck.  In addition, I feel you could study all this stuff but you won't really know what you need until you get going.  Learn things as you feel you need them, otherwise you can spend the next 10 years learning how to use and manage memcached, nosql, elastic clouds, mvc principles, unlimited numbers of design patterns, php, python, java, javascript, and so on and so forth.

Comment: And ALWAYS use prepared statements in database queries! From the beginning!!!

Comment: @Tadeck I know this type of question is generally frowned upon on SO, but I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Memcache, datamappers, frameworks, MVC for the first website? You have worries.. For most websites a 5$ webhost package is almost too good. Just make sure it supports latest PHP, comes with a database and supports .htaccess + mod_rewrite

Comment: @Tadeck - pretty much any code you write will look like crap when you look at it two years later, no matter how long you've been coding.

Comment: @andrewsi: It is obvious and "_pretty much any code you write will look like crap when you look at it two years later_" is not against what I said ("_after couple years, will look like crap_" and "_You will probably need to rewrite your whole site anyway_"). Anyway, _almost_ any code will need rewriting, not all. Additionally sometimes you won't need to rewrite it, because you will no longer need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off most of the things you mentioned (MemCache, etc) aren't needed for the vast majority of sites out there.

If you start off trying to build the "ultimate" site to handle millions of users, you will fail.  Utterly.  That type of architecture takes awhile to do, even by people who know exactly what they are doing.

To do this "right" means you are going to rewrite it several times.  FB, twitter, etc didn't start out with the architecture they have today.  They started small, tweaked, rewrote whole sections and at some point along the way, started over.  Then went through it again.

Just know that going in.  Put your site together, learn a few things, and launch.  You'll learn a lot more by watching how people interact with it and how your code responds than you will be trying to build the uber site now.

Another reason for starting small is that you might have an idea of what you want, but ultimately your users are going to stick around based on what they want.  Hopefully you can figure that out and iterate.

Comment: I think seeing all these concepts on SO is insightful but for a rookie like me was also a little overwhelming. Thanks for putting it into perspective.

Answer (score 0):

If you know nothing other than how to write your code, you should host your app on [PAAS cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) like [Heroku](http://heroku.com).

Security is a major concern, most newcomers make the same basic mistakes and get hacked easily.  IF you are going to store information about your users, you dont want a hacker getting that information.  With PAAS solutions like Heroku, they have ninjas taking care of their platform security.  And so many of the things you mentioned have to do with performance tuning, scaling etc., again taken care of by aforesaid ninjas.  When the site is live there will be so many things to do that you will practically be drowning in work if you decide to do everything yourself.